# htaccess subpage on subdomain to subpage on other subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have trouble finding out the right approach to make a 301 redirect from one subdomains page to another subdomains page.

For instance:

subpage1.mysite.com/contact
needs to be redirected to
subpage2.mysite.com/kontakt

*(i have a few hundred of these)*

I have a lot of 301 redirects in my .htaccess so far, but they only redirect from the maindomain mysite.com/page.

I cant make a 301 like this, right?
It does not work..

## 301

Redirect 301 http://subpage1.mysite.com/contact http://subpage2.mysite.com/kontakt

I only can access the primary htaccess file on the main domain (mysite.com)

Read some about RewriteCond but it seems they take all of my subpages and redirect them to the other subdomain. That is not exactly suitable for me, as the url's have changed names and are not identical on the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out by using this.
Taking the subdomain as RewriteCond

```
#Consultancy redirects
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^consultancy.madebydelta.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^about/$ http://testlab.madebydelta.com/om-os/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^industries/$ http://testlab.madebydelta.com/cases/ [R=301,NC,L]
```